# Attribute selected in option is deleted on HTML using Razor on asp.net-core-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add the attribute selected to an option inside a select, something like: `<option value="item" selected>item</option>`, but in an strange event the text `selected` is deleted when rendering the page.

For example I have the following code:

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  name="searchCode">
  <option value="0"> Nothing Selected</option>
  @foreach (string str in results) {
    string sel = "";
    if (str.Equals(searchCode)) {
      sel = "selected";
    }
    <option 
      value="@str"
      @sel>
      @str
    </option>
  }
</select>
```

In this if `searchCode == str` then the `@sel` is set as "selected" but the problem is that when the site is rendered the `@sel` attribute is not printed.

For example, it should print:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b" selected>b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

But instead it prints:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

If I change my code to this:

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  name="searchCode">
  <option value="0"> Nothing Selected</option>
  @foreach (string str in results) {
    string sel = "";
    if (str.Equals(searchCode)) {
      sel = "selected";
    }
    <option 
      value="@str"
      @sel>
      @str - @sel
    </option>
  }
</select>
```

I'll get something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a - </option>
  <option value="b">b - selected</option>
  <option value="c">c - </option>
</select>
```

So the attribute selected is correctly calculated but it's not printed as it should.

Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3733

What I did is to change `option` as `!option`.

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  name="searchCode">
  <option value="0"> Nothing Selected</option>
  @foreach (string str in results) {
    string sel = "";
    if (str.Equals(searchCode)) {
      sel = "selected";
    }
    <!option 
      value="@str"
      @sel>
      @str - @sel
    </!option>
  }
</select>
```

Comment: why did u choose !option over @(sel == "" ? "" : "selected")

Comment: Originally was something like `sel = "selected=\"selected\"";` and doing it as  @(sel == "" ? "" : "selected=\"selected\"") would be hard to read, but with the problems that arised I ended with an stripped version, also I didn't knew that I could do something like @(*), thanks for the tip

Comment: I asked that question because "!option" is a workaround but other solution is a standard code.

Answer (score 0):

1) create class for search criteria

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public string searchCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
}
```

2) add the default option before binding the list

```
var searchCriteriaObj = new SearchCriteria { searchCode = "bla bla bla" };
searchCriteriaObj.results = searchManager.getResults(searchCode);
searchCriteriaObj.results.Insert(0, " Nothing Selected");
```

3) bind the object by passing it (Controller) after getting the results.

```
ViewBag.criteria = searchCriteriaObject;
```

4) View page:

```
<select asp-for="ViewBag.criteria.searchCode" 
         asp-items="ViewBag.criteria.results">
</select>
```